# I need some guidance with my Git hook for pre-commit using Bash

Tags: git, bash, maven, githooks

Okay what I am attempting to do for our project is to have the developer choose if they want to commit or compile and then commit their code. This is because we have a code formatter that cleans up everything and currently on deployments many are not compiling first before their merge request. So, by having this file pushed onto all of the projects they will be reminded and have to pick one.

Currently the problem is trying to call the maven build at the moment. I cannot do a cd ../../ up to the project root folder. Suggestions on how to get this to work? Please I don't want to have a debate or discussion over why this was decided I just need to be pointed in the direction of how to get this to work. Thanks.

```
echo "CC to Compile and Commit"    "C to just compile"

while true; do
  read choice

  echo "Your choice was " $choice
  if ( "$choice" == CC" ) ; then
    cd ../../
    if [ mvn compile ] ; then
      echo "Compile was okay."
      echo "Continue with git commit."
    fi
  fi
  break
done
```

Comment: Also, just to clarify if you are not aware of hooks. The hooks folder resides within your project folder. e.g. C:\myProject\.git\hooks hence the need for cd ../../ in my script

Comment: try `pwd` before and after `cd ../../` what do you see?

Comment: sorry I should have also posted the error message I get. No matter what I put in e.g. pwd or the cd ../ it states on that line ##: [: mvn: unary operator expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
if ( mvn compile ) ; then
```

`[` is for runing test command in really

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the issue now is the shell won't prompt the user for input, it just goes into an endless loop where 'Your choice was' and nothing after that as no input was done. It is like it is just ignoring the line completely for *read choice*

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to create menus in bash is with the `select` command, here's an example (assumed to be run somewhere in the project directory):

```
#! /bin/bash

cmds=("Commit" "Compile and commit")
select cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    pushd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
    echo "You picked $cmd, working dir changed to $(pwd)"
    if [[ $cmd == "Compile and commit" ]]; then
        mvn compile
        if [[ $? != "0" ]]; then
            echo "Something went wrong"
        else
            echo "Compilation ok!"
        fi
    fi
    #git commit
    popd
    echo "Done, working dir now $(pwd)"
    break
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this select option. This along with the inclusion of the line of code 'exec < /dev/tty seemed to have fixed my issue. I will update the above code to reflect what works shortly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Without addressing either maven, or whether this is a reasonable thing to be doing in a pre-commit hook, there are several points to consider here:

- Git hooks are run in some directory.

  The precise current-working-directory for the hook varies.  If `git commit` is run anywhere *within* the repository tree, the pre-commit hook itself runs in the top level of the Git repository.  This is true regardless of which sub-directory you are in:

  ```
  $ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
  #! /bin/sh
  echo precommit: pwd = $(pwd)
  exit 1
  $ git commit
  precommit: pwd = [snip]/git
  $ cd Documentation
  $ git commit
  precommit: pwd = [snip]/git
  ```

  Note that this was *not* `.../git/Documentation` despite the fact that I was in the Documentation sub-directory.

  If `git commit` is run elsewhere, the current working directory may *not* be the top level of the repository, and may in fact be entirely unrelated to the repository itself, or the work-tree:

  ```
  $ cd /tmp
  $ git --git-dir=$HOME/src/kernel.org/git/.git commit
  precommit: pwd = /tmp
  ```

  It is therefore vital to: (1) constrain the location where `git commit` is run, or (2) **avoid using the current working directory at all.**  I put this in bold because of the third point below.  However, if you like, you can treat the current working directory as the work-tree: there is no need to attempt to `cd ../..` out of the `.git/hooks` directory.
- The standard input of a Git hook is often *not* connected to the user's terminal—assuming there *is* a user and a terminal in the first place.  For example:

  ```
  $ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
  #! /bin/sh
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
      echo precommit: stdin is a tty
  else
      echo precommit: stdin is NOT a tty
  fi
  exit 1
  $ git commit
  precommit: stdin is NOT a tty
  ```

  While you can attempt to open `/dev/tty`, this will only work if there *is* a `/dev/tty` to open, so there is a risk here.
- During a `git commit`, the *contents of the work tree* are **not** the contents that will be committed.  What will be committed is whatever is in the *index*.  Examining the work-tree is *only* correct if the index matches the work-tree.  You can test for this using the `require_clean_work_tree` shell function in `git-sh-setup`, which is in the `git --exec-path`, and `git --exec-path` has been added at the front of `$PATH`, so you can simply run:

  ```
  . git-sh-setup
  require-clean-work-tree "commit" "message to emit if work tree is not clean"
  ```

  for instance (the two arguments are the *action* and the *message to produce on failure*).

That said, the other issue you found is that:

```
[ expression ]
```

is the syntax to run the `[` command, passing it `expression ]` as its parameters.  (The `[` command is also known as the `test` command; when invoked as `test <expression>` it does not demand a final `]` argument, and otherwise works the same as when run as `[`.)  You wanted to run the `mvn` command, not the `[` or `test` command.